# direct sum of modules is a module itself

Tags: category-theory, modules, direct-sum

I am trying to learn modules for the first time. I have read that direct sum of two modules $M, N$ is a module itself, but I am not sure how to prove it. Can someone please explain it to me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well from a categorical perspective, you could define it as the limit (or colimit) of a two object discrete diagram, but that would require knowing the limit exists. Most first looks at it would construct the direct sum explicitly, and in doing so would have constructed the module structure along with the underlying set structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ and $N$ be left modules over a ring $R$. Define (as a set)
$$M \oplus N = \{(x,y) : x \in M, y \in N\}.$$
Define
$$ + : M \oplus N \times M \oplus N \rightarrow M \oplus N \qquad +((x,y), (x',y')) = (x,y) + (x',y') = (x+x', y+y').$$
Check this makes sense (i.e. well-defined).

Define
$$ \cdot : R \times M \oplus N \rightarrow M \oplus N, \qquad \cdot(\alpha, (x,y)) = \alpha \cdot (x,y) = (\alpha x, \alpha y).$$
Check this makes sense (i.e. well-defined).

Things left to verify:

- $r \cdot ((x,y) + (x',y')) = r \cdot (x,y) + r \cdot (x',y').$
- $(r+s) \cdot (x,y) = r \cdot (x,y) + s \cdot (x,y).$
- $(rs) \cdot (x,y) = r \cdot ( s \cdot (x,y)).$
- $1_R \cdot (x,y) = (x,y)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks @user203940 . I now see how to verify the properties. I am not sure how to check if addition and multiplication are well-defined. Sorry, I am a non-math person.

Comment: No problem. A map $f : A \rightarrow B$ is well-defined if for $x = y \in A$ we have $f(x) = f(y)$. Morally it just means that I don't have one $x$ value being sent to more than one $y$-value. Suppose $(\alpha,(x,y)) = (\beta,(x',y'))$. This means that $\alpha = \beta$, $(x,y) = (x',y')$ which means $x = x'$, $y = y'$. Now $\alpha \cdot (x,y) = (\alpha x, \alpha y) = (\beta x', \beta y') = \beta \cdot (x',y')$ and we're done (here I implicitly assumed scaling elements in the modules is well-defined).

Comment: It is a silly thing here since it is (seemingly) obvious, but it's always good for the soul to check.

Comment: ok thanks. I understand it now. Thanks a lot for your help! :)